# Custom List data structure implementing SequenceType with using of GeneratorOf struct

Tags: swift, generator, sequence

My attempts to understand Generators and Sequences lead me to an idea of implementing my own list data structure and implement protocols to use forIn loop. My code:

```
class GSList<T> : SequenceType
{
    var Next : GSList<T>?
    var Value : T

    init(_ value: T, next : GSList<T>?)
    {
        self.Value = value
        self.Next = next
    }

    func add(list: GSList<T>)
    {
       if (self.Next != nil)
       {
            self.Next?.add(list)
       } else
       {
            self.Next = list
       }
    }

    typealias Generator = GeneratorOf<GSList<T>>

    func generate() -> Generator
    {
        var current: GSList<T>? = self
        println(current?.Value)

        return GeneratorOf
            { () -> GSList<T>? in

                let returnValue = current
                current = self.Next
                println(self.Value)
                println(current?.Value)
                return returnValue
        }
    }
}


var list1 = GSList(1, next: nil)
var list2 = GSList(2, next: nil)
var list3 = GSList(3, next: nil)
var list4 = GSList(4, next: nil)
var list5 = GSList(5, next: nil)


list1.add(list2)
list1.add(list3)
list1.add(list4)
list1.add(list5)

var generator = list1.generate()

generator.next()
generator.next()
generator.next()
generator.next()
generator.next()
```

It doesn't have any compile time errors but the problem is that `current` variable is not updated with `Next` value in `generate()` method:

```
func generate() -> Generator
        {
            var current: GSList<T>? = self
            println(current?.Value)

            return GeneratorOf
                { () -> GSList<T>? in

                    let returnValue = current
                    current = self.Next
                    println(self.Value)
                    println(current?.Value)
                    return returnValue
            }
        }
```

So calling to next `generator.next()` always returns first item.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: GeneratorOf has been renamed AnyGenerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
current = self.Next
```

should be

```
current = current?.Next
```